# Test symmetry of effects of a categorical variable in linear model?

Tags: categorical-data, least-squares, symmetry

I have a linear model in which x and a categorical variable explain Y. 
The categorical variable contains 3 categories a positive, a negative and a neutral category. I am using the neutral category as the reference category.

```
Y = b1x1 + g1neg + g2pos + b2x2 + u,
```

where neg and pos are binary dummies. Now I would like to test whether the positive / negative effect was symmetric. I though of the following but I am non quite sure whether the binary variable led me to a wrong conclusion.

Because the equation can be easily re-written as:

```
Y = b1x1 + (g1-g2)neg + g2(pos+neg) + u 
(because Y = b1x1 + (g1 + g2 - g2)neg + g2pos +u)
```

the idea was to check whether the coefficient of neg, i.e. g1-g2, is significantly different from zero by just looking at the standard test statistic / p-value. If it wasn't, the effect should be symmetric. However, I seem to miss something because it does matter whether I include `neg` and `pos+neg` dummies or `pos` and `pos+neg`. One time the coefficient of the sum is significant, the other time not.

What's wrong about this approach? Is it just my interpretation? Is there a better way to test this kind of symmetry?

EDIT: 
I found `linearHypothesis` in the `car` package which failed to reject the hypothesis that

```
linearHypothesis(fit,"neg+pos=0")
```

which means that there is no evidence against the hypothesis of symmetry. 
Can anyone explain how this works (compared to my approach from above) and why my approach was not working..